# How does a resource leak take place?

Tags: java, stream, resources

It is advised that one should always close a Stream in a program in order to prevent serious resource leaks. But how does a resource leak actually take place? Any code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
 File[] lotsAndLotsOfFiles = ...

 for (File f: lotsAndLotsOfFiles) {
     InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
     // Use `is` ... But don't close it
 }
```

What happens with the above is that you end up with lots of files open. Under the hood, each one of those open files has an associated file descriptor. On Linux (for example) the OS only allows a process to have a limited number of file descriptors at any given time. If a process has already used up its quota of file descriptors, further attempts to open a file will fail.

At the Java level, the garbage collector (GC) will finalize any `OutputStream`, `InputStream`, `Reader` or `Writer` that it finds to be garbage. And the finalizer will call `close()` which will release the file descriptor. But the problem is that the garbage collector only runs occasionally. So if you leak too many file descriptors between successive GC runs, your application will run out, and probably die.

There are numerous examples of the right way(s) to prevent a resource leak in Java.

Comment: Does this(what you stated for Linux) happen in other OSs?? And is FileOnputStream the same as FileInputStream(you might have committed a typing mistake)

Comment: Definitely applies to other UNIX and UNIX-like oses ... including Mac OSX.  There are limits in Windows too, but I'm not sure how they are implemented.